# Space before proof

Tags: spacing, theorems, amsthm

I am trying to make LaTeX put no additional space between theorem and proof.
Here is my code:

```
\newtheorem*{pr3}{Theorem}
\begin{pr3}
   foo                                             
\end{pr3}
\begin{proof}[Proof:]
   bar
\end{proof}
```

Is there a way to do that only with `amsthm`/`amsmath` and how? I wanted to renewenvironment proof, however I couldn't find what is the best way to do that. So it would be great if someone can tell me where I can find such information (that could also be considered answer to the first question).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably don't want to remove the space after the proof, so the way should be

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \vspace{-\topsep}% remove the space after the theorem
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont
  \topsep0pt \partopsep0pt % no space before
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep
        \itshape
    #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
  \addvspace{6pt plus 6pt} % some space after
}
\makeatother
```

However a `proof` environment not preceded by a theorem will be typeset wrongly.

Comment: I didn't want to use negative vspace however as it is not constant like in the other answer, I think that this will do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could put a negative vertical space between theorem and proof, like so:

```
\newtheorem*{pr3}{Theorem}
\begin{pr3}
   foo                                             
\end{pr3}
\vspace{-1.5em}
\begin{proof}[Proof:]
   bar
\end{proof}
```

and you could wrap all into a [new command](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Customizing_LaTeX#New_commands) \theoremproof{theorem body}{proof body}.