# Spacing before and after proof environment

Tags: spacing

I would like spacings between all environments to be equal. However, before and after the proof environment, much more space is created than between normal environments.

Consider for instance the following example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools,lipsum}

\declaretheoremstyle{result_style}
\declaretheorem[style=result_style,name=Theorem]{thm}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]

    \begin{thm}
        \lipsum[2]
    \end{thm}

    \begin{thm}
        \lipsum[3]
    \end{thm}

    \begin{proof}
        A very short proof.
    \end{proof}

    \lipsum[4]

    \begin{thm}
        A very small theorem.
    \end{thm}

    \lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

Is there an easy way to fix this? What is the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: The method shown in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59769/13492 may help. You'll need to replace the dimensions there with numbers suitable to your purposes.

Comment: @murray Does the spacing remain flexible afterwards? For instance, if LaTeX needs to distribute spacing over the whole page, will it also be done before and after the proof environments?

Comment: For flexibility, you can include "plus" and "minus" amounts, as in: `8pt plus 4pt minus 2pt`. But you'll have to choose how much such slack to allow.